# Find the matrix representative of a linear transformation $T∈L(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^2).$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) =(x^2, \sin x)$. Find the matrix representative of a linear transformation $T∈L(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^2)$ which satisfies $\lim_{h→0}\frac{||f(x+h)−f(x)−T(h)||}{h}= 0.$

The norm part of this problem is throwing me off. I believe I have the right answer for the problem, its just the matrix of the derivatives of $f(x).$ I just don't know how to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Start from scratch and calculate:

$f(x+h)-f(x)=((x+h)^2-x^2, \sin (x+h)-\sin x)\Rightarrow $

$f(x+h)-f(x)-T(x)h=((x+h)^2-x^2-T_1(x)h, \sin (x+h)-\sin x-T_2(x)h)\Rightarrow $

$\frac{1}{h}\left(f(x+h)-f(x)-T(x)h\right)=\left(\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2-T_1(x)}{h}, \frac{\sin (x+h)-\sin x-T_2(x)}{h}\right).$

Now, if we choose $T_1(x)=2x$ and $T_2(x)=\cos x$, the limit in your question is zero, as required. And of course, $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$ are the derivatives of $f_1(x)=x^2$ and $f_2(x)=\sin x$.

The matrix representation of $T(x)$ is then $\begin{pmatrix}
2x\\ 
\cos x
\end{pmatrix}$ and it operates on the "vector" $t\in \mathbb R$ by $\begin{pmatrix}
2x\\ 
\cos x
\end{pmatrix}t= \begin{pmatrix}
2xt\\ 
(\cos x)t
\end{pmatrix}.$

Since the domain vector space is just $\mathbb R,$ we can take $t=1$ to recover the definition of the derivative usually seen in elementary calculus courses.

Comment: Thank you or your reply. If I could follow up, I was wondering how does the limit go to zero with those choices of T(x)? I might just not be seeing it.

Comment: Your $\sin x$ should be $\cos x$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yes thanks.

Comment: @JohnBeaver: Notice you have the definition of the derivative in each component. Now use the fact that the limit exists iff the limit of each component exists,individually. This latter item is easy to prove using the norm on $\mathbb R^2-$

Answer (score 1):

Since $T\in L(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^2)$, it is of the form
$$
T_x(y)=(a_xy,c_xy).
$$
for certain $a_x,c_x\in\mathbb R$.
So, for some fixed $x$, we want
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Big\|\big((x+h)^2-x^2-a_xh,\sin(x+h)-\sin x-c_xh\big)\Big\|}{h}=0.
$$
The quotient expands to (using the MVT)
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\big((2r_h-a_x)h+h^2\big)^2+\big(h\,(-c_x+\cos s_h)\big)^2}}{h},
$$
where $r_h,s_h$ are between $x$ and $x+h$. Considering the case $h>0$ (the case $h<0$ is similar) the square quotient (which has to go to zero) can be written as
$$
\Big((2r_h-a_x)+h\Big)^2+\Big(-c_x+\cos s_h\Big)^2.
$$
When $h\to0$ it becomes
$$
(2x-a_x)^2+(-c_x+\cos x)^2. 
$$
So, to be $0$, we need $a_x=2x$, $c_x=\cos x$. Then
$$
T_xh=(2xh,(\cos x) h). 
$$